# Why does line-height behave strange with universal selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-size

As I know in css we set `line-height` as integer because if we change font size in child elements then it recalculate appropriate value. This works fine except with universal selector because if I set `line-height:1.5em` in universal selector it does not create overlap. However, if I set `line-height:1.5em` in `div` it creates overlap.

```css
 *    {    line-height: 1.5em;       }

div  {   }

span {  font-size:4em;    }
```

```html
<div>ghghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhhghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>   <span>start hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhofhfh<br>fhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfgfgdfggdfgdfsgdfgdsfhjjghjhjfghjhfgjh end</span><br>.fhhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhjhjjghjghjhgjhgjghhfhhh</div>
```

```css
 *    {           }

div  {  line-height:1.5em;  }

span {  font-size:4em;    }
```

```html
<div>ghghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhhghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>   <span>start  span overlap line-height:1.5em; inside parent hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhofhfh<br>fhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfgfgdfggdfgdfsgdfgdsfhjjghjhjfghjhfgjh end</span><br>.fhhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhjhjjghjghjhgjhgjghhfhhh</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with universal selector.
The reason that that first example works because universal selector specify `div` and `span` both of them `line height`to `1.5 em` of its orignial `line-height`.

**You specify the line-height for span here**

For example two, you doesn't specify the `line-height` for span, so its line-height property will inherted from its parent container which is `div` (24 px line height)

Note that line-height is [inherted](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp).

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('span')).lineHeight)
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div')).lineHeight)
```

```css
*    {           }

div  {  line-height:1.5em;  }

span {  font-size:4em; 
}
```

```html
<div>ghghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhhghghfghdfhdhhghdhdfghfhhgfhfhghdhghgh<br>hfghdfghdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>   <span>start  span overlap line-height:1.5em; inside parent hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhofhfh<br>fhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfgfgdfggdfgdfsgdfgdsfhjjghjhjfghjhfgjh end</span><br>.fhhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhjhjjghjghjhgjhgjghhfhhh</div>
```

Comment: In last line of your first paragraph you say "1.5em of its original line-height." i cant understand what do you mean by "its original line-height" because as I understand, parent element (when inherit) or uni selector value became its original value

Comment: @user2022, So what I want to express is that the line-height for both span and div's line-height become 1.5 times as it used to be (the original line-height or default line-height for them is 18 px, but after specify it, both of them become 24px) Maybe I don't express very well.

Comment: thanks james you are awesome

Comment: @user2022, no problem,  glad I could help:)